# Unable to perform intersection on two different arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, intersection

I am trying to compare the two arrays, `$a` and `$b` and need their intersection.

```
$a  = [
    ['min' => 23 , 'max' => 987 , 'vmin' => 78],
    ['min' =>  3 , 'max' =>  87 , 'vmin' =>  8],
    ['min' => 'faryaad' , 'max' => 987 , 'vmin' => 65]
];

$b = [
    ['min' => 23 , 'max' => 987 , 'vmin' => 78],
    ['min' => 'faryaad' , 'max' => 87 , 'vmin' => 8],
    ['min' => 203 , 'max' => 9807 , 'vmin' => 780]
];

$i = array_uintersect($a,$b,"comp");

function comp($val1,$val2) {
    return $val1['min'] == $val2['min'] && $val1['max'] == $val2['max'] && $val1['vmin'] == $val2['vmin'] ;
}
print_r($i);
echo "<br />";
echo count($i);
```

In the two arrays, there is one common thing that is, `['min' => 23 , 'max' => 987 , 'vmin' => 78]` and I will expect the result to reflect this thing. But instead the result is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [min] => 23 [max] => 987 [vmin] => 78 ) [1] => 
Array ( [min] => 3 [max] => 87 [vmin] => 8 ) [2] => Array ( [min] => 
faryaad [max] => 987 [vmin] => 65 ) ) 
3
```

It just returns the whole array `$a`. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compare function is not supposed to return true (when equal) and false (when different), but a signed number as stated in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php):

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

As the compare function is only called for some pairs, just enough to determine the order, it is important to return a correct value, not just 1 when the two values are different. This is necessary as otherwise PHP may draw wrong conclusions and say: since *a < b* and *b < c*, *a* can never be equal to *c*, so I will not call the compare function for *a* and *c*.

Here is a compare function that produces the correct results:

```
$i = array_uintersect($a,$b,function($val1,$val2) {
    foreach ($val1 as $k => $v) {
        if(!isset($val2[$k])) return -1;
        if ($res = strcmp($v, $val2[$k])) break;
    }
    return $res;
});
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/653747) with some other data.

Output for the data in the question is:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [min] => 23
            [max] => 987
            [vmin] => 78
        )    
)
```

Comment: This returns an empty array.

Comment: @SuhailGupta, are you sure? I have added the link to eval.in so you can see it does return the expected output.

Comment: Don't know, why I am getting an empty array

Comment: Also, [at eval.in](https://eval.in/653740) here the result returned is incorrect. Now there should have been two rows in the output.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your feed-back. It turns out to be important to return a negative value when necessary.

Comment: I saw your suggesting for improving the code, but if you have a missing key, make sure to return a non-zero value. I updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

From [array_uintersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php) documentation:

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or
>   greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be
>   respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

You are returning boolean value `true` if equal, which in int is `1`. One dirty hack would be to return `false`, which would be `0` in `int`, meaning equal in comparison function.

```
function comp($val1,$val2) {
    return !($val1['min'] == $val2['min'] && $val1['max'] == $val2['max'] && $val1['vmin'] == $val2['vmin']) ;
}
```